# Ship to different address check box not showing up in woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, checkout

I need to enable and show ship to different address check box in WordPress woo-commerce. I have tried this code but did't worked:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_ship_to_different_address_checked', '__return_true' );
```

Comment: **This code will **only make** the checkbox "checked" if it's already displayed. This could come from your **WooCommerce settings:** 1) WC Settings > General > **"Shipping location(s)"** … 2) WC Settings > Shipping > **"Shipping options(s)"** … | … Or this can be related with your theme or a third party plugin. So you should also consider asking the theme authors

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `add_filter` function can accept 4 arguments, however you are only using 2, see [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_filter/) for the functional documentation. If you have been told to add that code into your `functions.php` file but it is not working then it may just be that the 3rd argument has not been set like so:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_ship_to_different_address_checked', '__return_true', 999);
```

Seeing as 999 is likely higher than the others, this should do the trick. However I also reccommend that you check to make sure that "Force shipping to the customer billing address" has not been enabled in `WooCommerce -> Shipping -> Shipping Options`.